# how to install ADOP a.k.a. accenture devops platfomr in local desktop without using server?

Tags: devops

I am working at a start company(around 50people) and would like adopt devops platform in our company, we came to know that ADOP a.k.a. Accenture devops has some good reviews so would like to install it and check how it works. we are able to install it for AWS server but we would like to see if we can install it in local desktop and run without using server?

Answer (score 2):

You can spend some time reading through the ADOP CloudFormation template and decomposing it into which actual Docker containers are being executed. It is definitely possible to run ADOP on a local VM - but is going to be quite hard.

For evaluation purposes, you can save all this time and effort by just starting a new AWS account - trying it out, and when done with the evaluation you can delete the whole platform with a click of a button in CloudFormation.

https://accenture.github.io/adop-docker-compose/

Answer (score 1):

You can use Quick Start https://accenture.github.io/adop-docker-compose/docs/quickstart/ to spin it up on your local machine.

> NB. the instructions will also work in anywhere supported by Docker Machine, just follow the relevant Docker Machine instructions for your target platform and then start at step 3 below and (you can set the VPC_ID to NA).

Also check out pre-requisites, it tells you all the tools that you need to have to run ADOP.

https://accenture.github.io/adop-docker-compose/docs/prerequisites/